# SQL Server triggers, how to output?

Tags: sql-server

Very new to SQL servers. I have an update trigger and would like to do some playing around / testing. I would like to select * from updated. But I can't think how to output this?

Is there an output I can send this too?

Comment: Hello friend, you will definetly find your answer here. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d246ecea-8d80-47f4-a955-472eae9ac36b/trigger-get-values-from-updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try output using PRINT command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx

```
DECLARE @VarName <type>;
SELECT @VarName = <column> FROM inserted;
PRINT @VarName;
```